# Add an event handler and instanciation of class

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, events

I have a problem of adding handlers : I explain

This is The **mediator** Class

```
Public Class ContratClassiqueViewModel
Implements IMediatorContratClassique

Public objucPTClassiqueViewModel As ucPTClassiqueViewModel

#Region "Constructors"

    Sub New(ByVal CtxViewModel As CtxViewModel, ByVal ucPlancheTravaux As ucPTClassiqueViewModel)
        objCtxViewModel = CtxViewModel
        objucPTClassiqueViewModel = ucPlancheTravaux
        objucPTClassiqueViewModel.AddHandlers()
        AddingHandlers()
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        objucPTClassiqueViewModel = New ucPTClassiqueViewModel(True)
        objucPTClassiqueViewModel.AddHandlers()
        AddingHandlers()
    End Sub
#End Region

  Private Sub AddingHandlers()
      AddHandler objucPTClassiqueViewModel.ChangeDateRealisation, AddressOf OnChangeDateRealisation
  End Sub

 Private Sub OnChangeDateRealisation(ByVal DatRealisation As Date?)
        Messagebox.Show("Raised")
 End Sub

End Class
```

The other class :

```
   Public Class ucPTClassiqueViewModel
        Implements IMediatorContratClassique

        Public objucParamPTViewModel As ucParamPTViewModel

        Sub New()

        End Sub


        Sub New(ByRef flag As Boolean)
            objucParamPTViewModel = New ucParamPTViewModel
        End Sub

        Public Sub AddHandlers()
            AddHandler objucParamPTViewModel.ChangeDateRealisation, AddressOf OnChangeDateRealisation
        End Sub

        Private Sub OnChangeDateRealisation(ByVal DatRealisation As Date?)
            RaiseEvent ChangeDateRealisation(DatRealisation)
        End Sub

End class
```

The problem is : when the program uses the default contructor of the class `ContratClassiqueViewModel` it works, but if it uses the other constructor :

```
  Sub New(ByVal CtxViewModel As CtxViewModel, ByVal ucPlancheTravaux As ucPTClassiqueViewModel)
            objCtxViewModel = CtxViewModel
            objucPTClassiqueViewModel = ucPlancheTravaux
            objucPTClassiqueViewModel.AddHandlers()
            AddingHandlers()
        End Sub
```

the method :

```
 Private Sub OnChangeDateRealisation(ByVal DatRealisation As Date?)
            Messagebox.Show("Raised")
     End Sub
```

will never be reached, because it seems that it adds handler to another instance of `ucPTClassiqueViewModel`. So I need to know :

1. Why this happens?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't "re-attach" the `objucPTClassiqueViewModel`, this should be the class' own responsibility (also do not forget to remove the handlers again afterwards!) Is there also a way you can show us how you using the classes? Since it is your program, i would assume that you can choose wether to give the same instance of the viewmodel to your created children, so i don't see why you switch between constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share the viewmodel between the classes, you should create first a shared viewmodel and then attach the same viewmodel all classes that need it / share it.

For this, you could create a Factory method, which knows about the viewmodel (if necessary creates one which isn't there yet, or warns the user that no viewmodel exists yet). The factory method then attaches the viewmodel to your classes that need it.

Any event thrown on the viewmodel would then iterate through to your listeners

An example of the Factory class could be the following

```
Public Class ViewModelFactory
    Public Shared Property ViewModel As IViewModel

    Public Shared Function Create(Of T As IHaveViewModel)() As T
        Dim newItem As T = Nothing

        Try
            newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()

            If ViewModel Is Nothing Then
                Throw New InvalidOperationException("Cannot create items that have a viewmodel before the viewmodel was created!")
            End If
            ' assign the viewmodel
            newItem.ViewModel = ViewModel

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error creating new {0}\r\nMessage: {1}\r\nStacktrace: {2}", GetType(T).FullName, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

        Return newItem
    End Function
End Class
```

This one would create classes that are based on the interface `IHaveViewModel` (which looks like this, eg)

```
Public Interface IHaveViewModel
    Property ViewModel As IViewModel
End Interface
```

To ease the implementations of the listeners, you could create an abstract class that attaches any listeners for you, and forwards the DateChangedEvent to an overridable method (or in my case, an abstract method, that must be implemented by any classes that inherit from it). A dispose method could be used to make sure that the handlers are removed when you dispose the class

```
Public MustInherit Class WatcherClass
    Implements IHaveViewModel, IDisposable

    Private _viewModel As IViewModel
    Public Property ViewModel As IViewModel Implements IHaveViewModel.ViewModel
        Get
            Return _viewModel
        End Get
        Set(value As IViewModel)
            If Object.ReferenceEquals(_viewModel, value) Then
                Return
            End If
            RemoveModelListeners()
            _viewModel = value
            AddModelListeners()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub AddModelListeners()
        If ViewModel Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        AddHandler ViewModel.DateChangedEvent, AddressOf Me.OnDateInModelChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveModelListeners()
        If ViewModel Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
        RemoveHandler ViewModel.DateChangedEvent, AddressOf Me.OnDateInModelChanged
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub OnDateInModelChanged(sender As Object, changeDate As DateTime?)

    Private disposedValue As Boolean

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                RemoveModelListeners()
            End If
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Any classes that then inherit from this implementation, must implement the DateChanged handler method, as these 2 classes do (eg)

```
Public Class ImplementedWatcher
    Inherits WatcherClass

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDateInModelChanged(sender As Object, changeDate As Date?)
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world from {0}", Me.GetType().FullName)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SecondWatcher
    Inherits WatcherClass

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDateInModelChanged(sender As Object, changeDate As Date?)
        Console.WriteLine("This one also heard me :)")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The `IViewModel` could look like the following

```
Public Delegate Sub DateChangedEventHandler(sender As Object, changeDate As DateTime?)

Public Interface IViewModel
    Event DateChangedEvent As DateChangedEventHandler
End Interface
```

With an implementation that could be the following

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Implements IViewModel

    Public Event DateChangedEvent(sender As Object, changeDate As DateTime?) Implements IViewModel.DateChangedEvent

    Private _date As DateTime?
    Public Property ChangeDate As DateTime?
        Get
            Return _date
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime?)
            If Object.Equals(value, _date) Then
                Return
            End If
            _date = value
            RaiseDateChanged(_date)
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overridable Sub RaiseDateChanged(changeDate As DateTime?)
        RaiseEvent DateChangedEvent(Me, changeDate)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        ' ViewModel
    End Sub
End Class
```

To test these classes, and how they "interact" with one another, you could use this main method (console program)

```
Sub Main()
    Dim viewModel As ViewModel = New ViewModel()
    ViewModelFactory.ViewModel = viewModel
    Dim watcher As IHaveViewModel = ViewModelFactory.Create(Of ImplementedWatcher)()
    Dim secondWatcher As IHaveViewModel = ViewModelFactory.Create(Of SecondWatcher)()

    Console.WriteLine("Setting date to today")
    viewModel.ChangeDate = DateTime.Now
    Console.WriteLine("Setting date to tomorrow")
    viewModel.ChangeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    Console.WriteLine("Setting date to next week")
    DirectCast(watcher.ViewModel, ViewModel).ChangeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)

    DirectCast(watcher, IDisposable).Dispose()
    DirectCast(secondWatcher, IDisposable).Dispose()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

This means in the end that all classes that have a shared viewmodel, also should be created over the Factory method, this one does the work of adding the viewmodel to the potential listeners. Any classes directly created from `ImplementedWatcher` or `SecondWatcher` will also listen, when they get a ViewModel assigned (over the property)

By setting the ViewModel to Nothing on the Watcher classes, the handlers would be removed, or you could do it by disposing the Watcher classes

I hope that gives you an idea to continue your program?

As a note, you could also implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface into the IViewModel class, and then you could be warned about all changes in the ViewModel (if you want to) and let the listeners decide to which properties they should react, then you don't have to create a multitude of Events.